# Nginx infinte redirection for kibana on centOS 7

Tags: nginx, kibana, centos7

I have no experience with reverse proxying, let alone nginx and am struggling.

Versions:

- kibana: 5.6
- nginx: 1.10.2

When I go to `elk.mydomain.com/kibana`, I am redirected in a loop until Firefox stops me after a massively long link like this:

`http://elk.mydomain.com/kibana/login?next=%2Fkibana%2Fkibana%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%252Fkibana%252Fkibana%252Flogin%253Fnext%253D%25252Fkibana%25252Fkibana%25252Flogin%25253Fnext%25253D%2525252Fkibana%2525252Fkibana%2525252Flogin%2525253Fnext%2525253D%252525252Fkibana........`

I have basically been trying small adjustments to every little thing with no luck.

`cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.conf`:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name elk.mydomain.com;
auth_basic "Restricted Access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.htpasswd;
location /kibana/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

`netstat -ntlpu | grep 5601`:

`tcp .... 127.0.0.1:5601  0.0.0.0:* ... LISTENING`

In `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` I have:

```
server.host: "localhost" # I have also tried "elk.mydomain.com"
server.basepath: "/kibana" # I have also tried ""
server.name: "a_label"
```

When i check locally with `httpie` (`http :5601`) I get `Found`.

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reverse-proxy-kibana/43647/14

I changed my `location` in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.conf` snippet to the following:

```
location ~ ^/kibana/(.*)$ {
        rewrite /kibana/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure what's happening but it works. Maybe someone with nginx awareness can explain this? Something to do with consuming part of link (as mentioned in that post).

Comment: Dude how did you get to the answer, I don't think I would have ever gotten that configuration , Nice, And Thanks Just 30min searching the answer